# How to programmatically add / remove a value for an unlimited multivalue field?

Tags: 7, entities

I was looking at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php but it seems one cannot use it as multi value fields are associate arrays. Any built in functions perhaps?

Here is an example array

> $myfield["und"][0]["value"] = 23424;
>
> $myfield["und"][1]["value"] = 76786;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`entity_metadata_wrapper()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_metadata_wrapper/7) function with entities (you'll find good examples [here](http://drupal.org/node/1021556)); it makes things a bit cleaner, but not that much.

Other than that, no - you're stuck using vanilla PHP for this, Drupal doesn't have any built in functions to help.

There's no reason you can't use `array_push` as normal though:

```
array_push($myfield[LANGUAGE_NONE], array('value' => 23424));
```

Although that's actually more verbose and less readable than the original.